# How to create table dynamically and retrieve all table data on button click using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to fill up my table value as per json array using JavaScript/jQuery and when user will click on button all table value should get. I am providing my code below.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" id="subTable">

 </table>
<div class="text-right">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="savebtn">Save</button>
 </div>
```

My JavaScript part is given below.

```
var resultArr=[];
$.ajax({
            url:"attendance_rule_db.php",
            type:"post",
            data:subject_data,
            success:function(response)
            {
                console.log('res subject',response);
                var html = '<tbody><tr style="background-color: #3c8dbc;  color: #fff;"><th>Subject</th><th>Attendance</th></tr>';
                var res1 = JSON.parse(response);
                $.each(res1.aaData,function(i,data){
                    var data={'sub_code':data.subject_code,'sub_name':data.subject_name,'attendance':''};
                    resultArr.push(data);
                    html=html+'<tr><td>'+data.subject_name+'<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="sub'+i+'" placeholder="enter attendance" name=""></td></tr>';
                }); 


            },
            error:function()
            {
                toastr.error('Unable to process please contact support');
            }
        });
```

Here I need to display the subject name inside the table cell and another cell will contain one text field. When user will click on `save` button all rows text field value will get with `subject_name and subject_code` inside one json array.

Comment: Well... what exactly is your issue? What doesn't work? Do you have some sort of error message with something?

Comment: No, actually I can not append data inside the table as expected and also need to get the array of data after click on save button.

Comment: Well to start with you aren't even doing anything with `html`, you should set it to your table like `$('#subTable').html(html);` after the `each` function